# Unable to remove certain symbols from a string?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, formatting

```
#Loading of the .csv data from the Happy Planet Index and WHO, defining and clearing the data for RDF conversion.
hsi_data = pd.read_csv("HPI_Main.csv", sep=';')
hsi_data = hsi_data.replace(to_replace=[" ", "%"], value="", regex=True)
hsi_data = hsi_data.replace(to_replace=",", value=".", regex=True)
hsi_data = hsi_data.fillna("unknown")
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
hsi_data.columns = hsi_data.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
for x in hsi_data["GDP/capita"]:
    re.sub(r'$', ' ', x)
    print(x)
```

The whole point is to remove $ sign from the data in GDP/capita, and convert it into a integer. However nothing seems to remove the symbol, no re.sub nor replace or remove, its like it isnt detecting it?

Comment: Hi, not sure I understand what is your problem, but what does this outputs - print("this is a $ sign".replace("$", "Dollar")) ? Maybe try a str() conversion

Comment: Style tip: Your first comment is 116 characters, far above the [PEP 8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Remember, your code is read alot more than it is written, so add a line break and split your comment in two.

Comment: 1. The symbol '$' in regular expressions means "line end", so you should escape it.
2. Remember to assign the result of the function to the variable.

That is, the code should be fixed as following:
`x = re.sub(r'\$', ' ', x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the `$` sign and convert the value to an integer, you could replace the last `3` lines of the above code with the following -

```
hsi_data['GDP/Capita'] = hsi_data['GDP/Capita'].str.replace('$','').astype(int)
```

Comment: This solved it, and the astype solution simplified it even more! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the Happy Planet data. The problem you are having with `re` replacement is that the `$` sign is a special character in a regular expression, so must be escaped. This works:

```
x = " $67,646 "
z = re.sub("\\$", " ", x)
print(z)
```